# HTML id tag and JS files in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the image below as a screenshot of my Blazor Page.
[image]

My problem is the CSS seems to work fine but the JS files don't.

I have my script file is my _Host.cshtml file at the end just before closing the body tag as seen below

```
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Bulkit js -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/landingv5.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/auth.js"></script>
```

I have a navigation component set up as normal
Code below

```
  <div class="navbar-end">
     <!-- Navbar item -->
     <a class="navbar-item is-slide is-centered-tablet" href="#features">Features</a>
      <!-- Navbar item -->
      <a class="navbar-item is-slide is-centered-tablet" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
```

and a snippet of the section I want to go to on the Index.razor component

```
<!-- Pricing section -->
<div id="pricing" class="section is-medium">
<div class="container">
<div class="columns is-vcentered">
<div class="column is-5 is-centered-mobile">
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out using the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code&WT.mc_id=devto-blog-jeliknes).

Just a little snip of the long good read.

I had to do a

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19424.4
```

and then a

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -o MyApplicationName
```

and imported my file assets and modified the index.html generated with my layout files.

GIF below

[image]